# Why does serde's derivation of Serialize/Deserialize produce code in const _: () block?

Tags: rust, compile-time, rust-proc-macros

Note: this question isn't specifically about `serde`: it is about procedural macros and const function.

I'm studying the code produced by [serde](https://serde.rs)'s derive macros for `Serialize` and `Deserialize`, and I haven't figured out why all of its code is inside a `const _: ()`.

For example,

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyNewType(i32);
```

expands to (using `cargo expand`):

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
#[allow(non_upper_case_globals, unused_attributes, unused_qualifications)]
const _: () = {
    #[allow(unused_extern_crates, clippy::useless_attribute)]
    extern crate serde as _serde;
    #[automatically_derived]
    impl<'de> _serde::Deserialize<'de> for MyNewType {
        fn deserialize<__D>(
            __deserializer: __D,
        ) -> _serde::__private::Result<Self, __D::Error>
        where
            __D: _serde::Deserializer<'de>,
        {
         // generated implementation omitted for brevity
        }
    }
};
```

I discovered that if I carefully copy the stuff *inside* the `const _: () = {...}` block and paste it back in my source code after removing the `#[derive(Deserialize)]` tag, it all seems to compile and the deserialization continues to work just fine.
So what purpose does putting everything in the `const _: ()` block serve in my program?

Answer (score 5):

It prevents the introduction of new names into the outer scope. When you copy-paste into your own scope, you're copying this line as well.

```
#[allow(unused_extern_crates, clippy::useless_attribute)]
extern crate serde as _serde;
```

This introduces a name called `_serde` into the current scope. That could potentially conflict with your own code if you don't know to look for it. And worse, if multiple `Deserialize` macros expand in the same scope, then they'll *both* introduce the same name, which is a problem.

```
const _: () = {
  ...
}
```

So we run a block to get a new local scope that won't interfere with anything. The block returns `()`, which we neglect to bind. I'm not entirely sure why they needed a variable at all (instead of just the curly braces), though I suspect it may be to suppress unused variable warnings or prevent dead code elimination.

Comment: You can't put a block at the top level. The only other reasonable things would be a function or a module, but those both introduce names. Consts can be unnamed.